# Impute missing value in time series data with past observation in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns of timestamp and energy usage. The timestamp is taken for every min of the day i.e., a total of 1440 readings for each day. I have few missing values in my dataframe.

I want to impute those missing values with the value from the same day and same time from the previous week. If a previous week is also NaN, use the value from two weeks before. In short, I want to impute the missing data from previous values like this:
a week before, two weeks before, three weeks before, yesterday, the day before yesterday, and if all of these values were NaN use something like the average of the whole dataset.

Here's a example of the data:

```
                    mains_1
timestamp   
2013-01-03 00:00:00 155.00
2013-01-03 00:01:00 154.00
2013-01-03 00:02:00 NaN
2013-01-03 00:03:00 154.00
2013-01-03 00:04:00 153.00
... ...
2013-04-30 23:55:00 NaN
2013-04-30 23:56:00 182.00
2013-04-30 23:57:00 181.00
2013-04-30 23:58:00 182.00
2013-04-30 23:59:00 182.00
```

Right now I have this solution that works:

```
dfH = proxy.shift(freq='1H')
df1 = proxy.shift(freq='1D')
df2 = proxy.shift(freq='2D')
df7 = proxy.shift(freq='7D')
df14 = proxy.shift(freq='14D')
df21 = proxy.shift(freq='21D')

df_concat = pd.concat([proxy, dfH.mains_1.rename('hour'),
                  df1.mains_1.rename('one'),
                  df2.mains_1.rename('two'),
                  df7.mains_1.rename('seven'),
                  df14.mains_1.rename('fourteen'),
                  df21.mains_1.rename('twenty_one')],
                 axis=1)

df_loc = df_concat.loc[(df_concat.index < pd.to_datetime('2013-5-1'))]

conditions = [
    df_loc['mains_1'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['seven'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['fourteen'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['twenty_one'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['one'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['two'].isnull().eq(1),
    df_loc['mains_1'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['seven'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['fourteen'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['twenty_one'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['one'].isnull().eq(1),
    df_loc['mains_1'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['seven'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['fourteen'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['twenty_one'].isnull().eq(1),
    df_loc['mains_1'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['seven'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['fourteen'].isnull().eq(1),
    df_loc['mains_1'].isnull().eq(1) & df_loc['seven'].isnull().eq(1),
    df_loc['mains_1'].isnull().eq(1),
]

choices = [df_loc['hour'], df_loc['two'], df_loc['one'], df_loc['twenty_one'], df_loc['fourteen'], df_loc['seven']]

df_loc['filled'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=df_loc['mains_1'])
```

The result looks something like this:

```
                    mains_1 7_day   14_day  21_day  one_day two_day 1_hour  final
timestamp                               
2013-04-30 23:50:00 184.00  200.00  139.00  139.00  131.00  218.00  178.00  184.00
2013-04-30 23:51:00 NaN     207.00  138.00  139.00  130.00  188.00  178.00  207.00
2013-04-30 23:52:00 183.00  228.00  139.00  138.00  131.00  NaN     178.00  183.00
2013-04-30 23:53:00 183.00  228.00  139.00  NaN     131.00  187.00  178.00  183.00
2013-04-30 23:54:00 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     130.00  187.00  146.00  130.00
2013-04-30 23:55:00 182.00  226.00  139.00  139.00  NaN     186.00  134.00  182.00
2013-04-30 23:56:00 182.00  NaN     140.00  139.00  130.00  187.00  134.00  182.00
2013-04-30 23:57:00 181.00  226.00  140.00  139.00  130.00  186.00  134.00  181.00
2013-04-30 23:58:00 NaN     NaN     140.00  139.00  130.00  186.00  134.00  140.00
2013-04-30 23:59:00 182.00  224.00  140.00  138.00  130.00  185.00  134.00  182.00
```

So this solution works fine right now. My question is, is there a more elegant way to do this in python?
Also, after looking back at three or four weeks in past, I want a more general solution, instead of yesterday, the day before yesterday, and the last hour. For example, I want something like the mean of past two months or something.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html

Comment: @ifly6 It's not what I'm looking for.